# Puma gem fails to build native extensions on macOS 12 (Monterey) with Ruby 3.1

Tags: ruby, macos, build, rubygems, native

When looking at the build log, the first error noted is `error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled`. Ruby is now using a feature that's off-by-default in compilers on modern macOS versions.

Comment: This is getting downvoted as not showing research, despite the title of the question describing the gem, OS version and Ruby version, the question showing the exact important log line of interest and the explanation, followed by (this being a Q&A fix) the correct resolution.

I don't really understand what more people want from it. If you could answer in comments instead of downvoting what appears to be a useful and appropriately detailed Q&A, I'd appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 5):

This can be fixed via Bundler, if you're using it for gem installation, with:

```sh
bundle config set --global build.puma --with-cflags=-fms-extensions
```

You *might* to be able to install it one-shot by temporary setting C compilation flags if using `gem install ...` directly, but I've not tried this.

```sh
CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fms-extensions" gem install puma
```